# Not able to login in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, login

> have not logged out yourself, this could mean that there is some installation problem or that you may be out of disk space. Try logging in with one of the fail safe sessions to see if you can fix this problem

In Linux Mint Sarah. On login time I am getting this issue.

[image]

Comment: "_you may be out of diskspace_"

Comment: The screenshot shows "Try logging in with one of the failsafe sessions". Have you tried that? What happened? Did you get beyond discovering whether it was an installation problem or a diskspace problem? I googled for "linux mint failsafe session" - it seems there's a lot of information online, in the Mint forums particularly, but until let us know what you've tried it's hard to give an answer.

Comment: thanks John for your response... i didn't tried in failsafe  sessions ...i tried login through recovery mode...but its also not worked and i installed ant after that i getting this issue... its showing error msg in view details section   "export : /home/mohammed/utility/eclipse/ant 1.9.6"